# Flutter Futurebuilder inside TabBarView not triggering the future after initial application load while switching between tabs?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am new to flutter and trying to implement a tabview in homePage in the flutter app.

The first tab is populated from data from firebase remote config and second tab is populated by using Futurebuilder. When I switch the tabs the future function is not triggering. It is only triggered during initial application load. Whenever I switch tabs and come back to 2nd tab. The futurebuilder's future function is not triggered again.

Can someone give any solutions for this.?

```
Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisCount: isTablet ? 2 : 1,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    children: [
                      FutureBuilder(
                          future: _getBookmarks,
                          builder:
                              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            var listWidget;
                            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.done) {
                              if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                                listWidget = Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                  child: Text("No Favorites to Display!"),
                                ));
                              } else {
                                listWidget = ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    final bookmarks = snapshot.data[index];
                                    return BuildFavoriteCard(
                                        bookmarks, context);
                                  },
                                );
                              }
                            } else {
                              listWidget = Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }
                            return listWidget;
                          })
                    ],
                  ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example combining the TabBar and FutureBuilder examples of the Flutter documentation.

If you run this, you will see that a new future is created each time you navigate to the first tab (since the TabBarView's content is rebuilt).

I would assume that this is currently not working for you since your future `_getBookmarks` is defined somewhere higher up in the widget tree (in the part that is not rebuilt by switching tabs).

The solution would be to move the future inside your TabBarView widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              ],
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: MyStatefulWidget(),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future<String>? _calculation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => 'Data Loaded',
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future:
            _calculation, // calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.check_circle_outline,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
              ),
            ];
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              )
            ];
          } else {
            children = const <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              )
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. I refactored the code so that the widget is rebuilt each time tab is switched.